# How to go about debugging semi-random PC restarts. (In game: Dota 2)

Tags: graphics-card, crash, gpu, reboot, overheating

I've been playing Dota 2 for a while on my home PC, but lately it seems to be crashing semi-randomly.

**Symptoms:**

From alive to dead in 1 second. No pre-warning whatsoever.

1. Mostly just before big team battles (EG lots of spells animations/particles), or
2. as the ancient gets destroyed (EG lots of spells animations/particles) or
3. just randomly during the game.

This game isn't the most graphic intense game by a long shot I believe...

I've also added 2 additional fans to hopefully rule out the overheating option.

My thinking was its GPU related, so I ran a GPU stress test using an app called FurMark, and also after that using FutureMark... nothing happened out of the ordinary.

I'm unaware of general crash logs or where i'd find them? Know of anything (3rd party tools or apps) I'd be able to access to help debugging?

Comment: Turn off the option that automatically resets the OS on crashes. You should be able to see the BSOD, with the root caue of the issue hopefully (it doesn't always) displayed.

Comment: This could be CPU or memory related too. Did you stress test them as well as the GPU?

Comment: Create a boot disk with MemTest86+ to stress test your RAM. You can download the ISO from here: http://www.memtest.org/    You can torture test your CPU with this software: http://www.playtool.com/pages/prime95/prime95.html

Comment: look if you have kernel 41 Events in the eventlog and if yes, try this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504

Comment: Yes! there are kerner 41 events. Will look into this a bit further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@magicandre1981's comment got me pointed in the right direction.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504#method3

The system randomly restarts and no Stop error BugcheckCode is listed, or the computer is completely unresponsive (hard hang)

Turned out my power supply was failing (can only assume a manufacturer defect as the previous power supply was about a month or 2 old)

Comment: For future readers - power supply issues are a **common** cause of *"random re-starting under heavy load"*. Replacing the power supply, possibly with a higher-wattage model than the original, will often solve the problem.